# Php connect to WAMP mysql server

Tags: php, база-данных, wamp-server

Я установил WAMPServer, открыл database в phpMyAdmin,
но не могу подключиться к database.

Код:

```
<?php


echo "1";

$db_host = "localhost:8080";

echo "2";

$db_username = "tot";


echo "3";

$db_pass = "";

echo "4";

$db_name = "test_database";

echo "5";

@mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_pass") or die ("success");

echo "6";

@mysql_select_db("$db_name") or die ('Work');


echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

Он доходит до 5, 
и у меня нету кода -- `$db_pass = "";`

Comment: @David Kern, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  //соединение с базой данных при помощи функции mysql_connect()
  //в аргументах функции укажите имя сервера, логин и пароль. 
  $db = mysql_connect("сервер","логин","пароль");
  //функция mysql_select_db() выбирает текущую 
  //базу данных с именем "komtet_test"
  mysql_select_db("komtet_test" ,$db);
  //функция mysql_query() выполняет запрос на выборку данных 
  //результирующий набор данных хранится в переменной $sql
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM links" ,$db);
  //после получения данных начнём формирование HTML-таблицы 
  echo ("<table border ='1'>");
  //выводим строку заголовков 
  echo ("<tr><td>Адрес</td><td>Описание</td></tr>");
  //функция mysql_fetch_row() извлекает одну строку из результата 
  //и сохраняет её в массиве $tablerows
  while ($tablerows = mysql_fetch_row($sql))
  {
  //теперь в цикле для каждой полученной строки сделаем вывод 
  //$tablerows[1] соответствует полю "url" 
  //$tablerows[2] соответствует полю "description" 
  echo("<tr><td><a href="/info/tech/$tablerows[1]">$tablerows[1]
        </a></td><td>$tablerows[2]</td></tr> ");
  }
  echo "</table>";
  //закрытие соединение (рекомендуется)
  mysql_close($db);
  ?>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за коммент, но это не очень мне помогает, я хочу просто подключиться database, может, проблема в wamp  или еще где ...

Comment: попробуй установи другого пользователя на твою базу данных с паролем!